# AWS ECS doesn't start an EC2 Instance when AutoScaling Group has desiredCapacity as 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

**Scenario 1:**

I have created the following resources in the order:

- Create AutoScalingGroup/ASG (with minCapacity 1)
- Create ECS Cluster
- Attach AutoScalingGroup as Provider to ECS

The problem I face in this case is, an EC2 gets launched by ASG and that doesn't connect to ECS because ECS_CLUSTER value is different from the actual cluster name. This feels obvious because ASG is launched before provider is added to cluster.

**Scenario 2:**

- Create AutoScalingGroup/ASG (with minCapacity 0, desiredCapacity 0)
- Create ECS Cluster
- Attach AutoScalingGroup as Provider to ECS
- Add a Task Def and create a Service

The service cannot launch because of an error: "No Container Instances were found in your cluster"

Scenario 2 confuses me - It isn't clear if ECS Scaling Policy would create the very first instance too or not?

---

Some solutions propose to keep the min capacity as 1, so that it works. But if I do that, I end up into Scenario 1, where the first EC2 instance can't register with ECS.

Comment: @marcin I have been trying with Fargate which has been more seamless than EC2 option. I will get around to trying EC2 again, but I guess using userData would be the way to go anyway. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `user_data` in your Launch Configuration or Template to correctly setup the instances for ECS. This includes providing a claster name as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name
EOF
```

Comment: I am working on creating a new stack to check if the above works. I would be marking this as correct once I am done. In the meantime, I have been thinking the same, to use user data, but when I usually create using CDK, it adds more data apart from ECS_CLUSTER, want to confirm on that.

Comment: @RajivSeelam There are many options you can add to your `ecs.config`. The above is bare minimum.